# Why isn't Blockhound recognizing Ktor threads as non-blocking?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, ktor, blockhound

I tried to get BlockHound working with Ktor like this.

```
BlockHound.install(CoroutinesBlockHoundIntegration())
```

But it doesn't detect blocking calls inside routing endpoints. Has anyone had any luck with this? I guess the problem is that Blockhound doesn't recognize Ktor threads as non-blocking threads, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to configure Blockhound without causing other problems.